# bash: assign variable and print to stdout in same command

Tags: bash, csv, json

I'm working on a bash script that reads a csv file with fields and field values and creates a json string out of the input.

For simplicity I have a bash script that takes in two arguments simulating above script.

```
#!/bin/bash

fieldValue1=$1
fieldValue2=$2

jsonString='{"field1":"'$fieldValue1'", "field2":"'$fieldValue2'"}'
echo $jsonString
```

When I call above script with two arguments, I correctly get below output:

```
 ./test.sh "abc" "def"
{"field1":"abc", "field2":"def"}
```

What I am trying to achieve now, is to be able to assign and print a variable in the first argument, then reuse the variable from the first argument in the second argument.

For example when I call the script with below sample arguments (the syntax is flexible):

```
 ./test.sh "VAR=abc;echo $VAR" "$VAR"
```

then the output should look like this:

```
{"field1":"abc", "field2":"abc"}
```

The practical use of this is that for example for the real script inside the large input file, I only have to maintain a date once:

```
startDate1,field2,startDate2
var startDate=1/1/2020;echo $startDate,someValue,$startDate
2/1/2020,someOtherValue,$startDate
```

Does anybody have an idea on how to best achieve above output?

Comment: You realise that none of your variables in your script is double quoted? That's poor programming style. Try `fieldValue1="$1"` and `jsonString="{\"field1\":\"$fieldValue1\", \"field2\":\"$fieldValue2\"}'` or `jsonString='{"field1":"'"$fieldValue1"'", "field2":"'"$fieldValue2"'"}'` if you must, and finally `echo "$jsonString"`.

Answer (score 2):

Why not `var=abc; ./test.sh "$var" "$var"` ?

Or, call your script with one argument, and the script handles the missing value:

```
#!/bin/bash
fieldValue1=$1
fieldValue2=${2:-$1}
...
```

then: `./test.sh foo` outputs `{"field1"="foo", "field2"="foo"}`

---

Note that's not JSON: use a colon not equal: `{"field1":"foo", "field2":"foo"}`

Also you're leaving the variables unquoted when you assign the jsonString variable. Do this

```
jsonString='{"field1":"'"$fieldValue1"'", "field2":"'"$fieldValue2"'"}'
# ......................^............^...............^............^
# or
jsonString="{'field1':'$fieldValue1', 'field2':'$fieldValue2'}"
# or
printf -v jsonString '{"field1":"%s","field2":"%s"}' "$fieldValue1" "$fieldValue2"
```

---

Also, you should protect against the values containing quote characters:

```
printf -v jsonString '{"field1":"%s","field2":"%s"}' \
    "${fieldValue1//\"/\\\"}" \
    "${fieldValue2//\"/\\\"}"
```

Then

```
$ ./test.sh 'he said "foo"'
{"field1":"he said \"foo\"","field2":"he said \"foo\""}
```

---

Based on updated requirements. Assigning the variable **must** be a separate step. You're also missing the `$(...)` [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) syntax

First an updated script:

```
#!/bin/bash
pairs=()
for ((i=1; i<=$#; i++)); do
    value=${!i}
    pairs+=( "$(printf '"%s":"%s"' "field$i" "${value//\"/\\\"}")" )
done
IFS=,
echo "{${pairs[*]}}"
```

Then invoke it like this

```
startDate=1/1/2020
bash test.sh "$startDate" someOtherValue "$startDate" "$(date -u -d "$startDate 1 hour" "+%FT%TZ")" "anotherValue"
```

and get this output:

```
{"field1":"1/1/2020","field2":"someOtherValue","field3":"1/1/2020","field4":"2020-01-01T01:00:00Z","field5":"anotherValue"}
```

Comment: I fixed the json string by using : instead of = I also added an explanation or the "real" use case to this post, which is having an large input file with values and  declaring and using a variable only once in the input file instead of having to maintain a value in many places inside the input file...

Answer (score 0):

If you enclose your first argument within `$()`, you'll get the output you want.

```
./test.sh "$(VAR=abc; echo $VAR)" "def"
```

In this case, bash will use a subshell to execute setting `VAR=abc`, followed by `echo $VAR`, and then STDOUT from that subshell is being used as `test.sh` argument `$1`.

---

**EDIT**

To get both variables assigned from a single setting of the variable, you'll need to get both from the subshell.

```
./test.sh $(VAR='abc'; echo $VAR $VAR)
```

By removing the quotation marks around `$()`, we know catch the first word in the STDOUT of the subshell as `$1`, and the second word as `$2`.

However, since `$VAR` isn't being set in the parent shell, you can't use `$VAR` directly.

You could however, use the subshell to set `$VAR`.

```
VAR=$(VAR=abc; echo $VAR) ./test.sh $VAR $VAR
```

or, for readability

```
VAR=$(FOO=abc; echo $FOO) ./test.sh $VAR $VAR
```

Comment: Does not answer the question: he wants to use the variable for the 2nd parameter as well. And since you're assigning it in a subshell, the variable is not available there.

Comment: This seems to be on the right track, but when I try to reference VAR in the second argument it turns out to be empty: ./variableAssignmentTest.sh "$(VAR=abc; echo $VAR)" "$VAR"

Comment: Yeah.  That's because VAR isn't being set in the current shell.  It's being set in the sub shell, and then we're catching it as STDOUT.

Comment: If you assign `$VAR` in the parent shell, then you could use it to pass arguments to `test.sh`.

Comment: Is there a way to export the variable from the sub to the parent?

Comment: The only way I know how to do that is to capture it on STDOUT.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you are trying to reinvent `csvjson` from [CSVkit](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/):

```
$ cat file.csv
A,B,C
1,2,3
4,5,6

$ csvjson file.csv
[{"A": 1.0, "B": 2.0, "C": 3.0}, {"A": 4.0, "B": 5.0, "C": 6.0}]

$ csvjson -i 4 file.csv
[
    {
        "A": 1.0,
        "B": 2.0,
        "C": 3.0
    },
    {
        "A": 4.0,
        "B": 5.0,
        "C": 6.0
    }
]
```

Comment: Similar but with variables: e.g. A,B,C\nVAR=1/1/20;echo $VAR,$VAR,3

Comment: @BernieLenz I'm not sure I understand. Could you give an example CSV input file that you are working on and what the JSON should look like after having processed it?

Comment: Updated the post with an example

Comment: @BernieLenz You made it very unclear. You have shell code in your CSV file?

Comment: Correct. That's the reason I have my own shell script instead of using any tools.